# Does a dryer belt have to ride in the groove if its drum?

Tags: dryer

I inherited a Maytag Neptune Drying Center, which has a lower tumble dryer and an upper drying cabinet, when I purchased my home. When replacing the belt, I noticed that the belt has never rode in the drum's groove. I can tell by the wear marks. The drum is installed with its groove towards the back of the dryer and I can't get the belt to move into the groove.

[image]

Comment: Belts should be in straight line between both pulleys(motor and drum).  If belt in motor pulley is straight, then that is where it goes around the drum.

Comment: `I can't get the belt to move into the groove` ... step back, take a breath and think about what you are doing

Comment: Do not force the issue, if the dryer operates normally. Otherwise, call the services.

Comment: It operates fine and the pulleys are aligned. It seems odd to have this groove in the drum for no reason though.

Comment: maybe a different motor, or different model. uses the groove,